# get value from POST request in Django

Tags: python, django, post, python-requests, request

I want to get the value of the key 'result' but every time I'm trying to get it it becomes empty

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    result = request.POST
```

[after printing the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvSWN.png)

as you can see there is something there but when I'm trying to print:

```
request.POST.get('result')
```

or

```
request.POST['result']
```

I'm getting an empty string

Answer (score 2):

Try this `values = request.POST.getlist('result')`, as `request.POST.get('result')` returns only the last element in array, it's `''` in your case. Check [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1130) discussion.